# Bootstrap Containers are stacked on small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently following a web development course on Udemy, and there is a project I worked on, but at the very end I noticed that 2 of my Bootstrap containers are being stacked when the browser gets to a small width.

I have a live example here, you should be able to read all the source code:
http://appiedevelops.net76.net
I am talking about the 'Why This App Is Awesome' container and the download container. When the browser is small, they stack on top of each other.

Regards

Comment: That's what bootstrap does - it changes the layout to suit the width. It looks good on mobile phones. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: @AndrewShepherd By "stack on top of each other" he means overlap so they're unreadable.

Comment: My question is, how do I fix this?

Comment: @SnoopDoge I answered a few minutes before you posted your comment, did you try my solution? If so, did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following code from the end of your document:

```
<script>
  $(".section").css("height",$(window).height());
</script>
```

This is giving the `height: 633px;` style to your div with `id="about"`.

What was happening is that the content in your `about` div was overflowing its height.

Comment: I haven't set a height for #about

Comment: @SnoopDoge One of your scripts did, because I see `<div class="container section" id="about" style="height: 633px;">` in the final version of your page (though I don't see it in the original page source).

Comment: I understand what you mean now :) I had a Javascript to set the height of the containers to the full browser height, but I should have only done it for the landing container. Thanks for helping!